# Mysql error Unknown column in where clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql, string

Friends, i am new to the world of php and database programming. I apologize ahead if i fail to communicate well using the right terminologies.

Table 1

```
Id  |  name  | lastName | age
===============================
1   | Jane   | Kot      | 20
2   | Ann    | Ama      | 17
```

Table 2

```
Id | lastName | bonus | sex
==============================
1  | kot      | 50%   | male
2  | Jack     | 20%   | male
```

I want to join the two tables where `table1.lastName = table2.lastName`. In the illustration above, I would be looking forward to having “1 Jane 20 (all from table1) 1 50% male (all from table2) returned.
But I would choose to display any of the data, hyper-linking it to display the entire record in another page using the common field (lastName)

Example: Jane, displayed in `page1.php`, when clicked will display the combined record in `page2.php`.
 Jane (now hyper-linked in  `page1.php`) ---------clicked---------> 1 Jane 20  1 50% male (displayed in `page2.php`)
Please help me. I apologize for my poor mode of expressing my problem. Thanks

CODE FOR `PAGE1.PHP`

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.lastname = table_2.lastname";
$result = mysql_query ($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    echo '<table border="1">';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'. $row['name'].'<br>'.'</td>';
    echo '<td><a href="page2.php? lastName=' . $row['lastName'] . '">VIEW DETAILS</a></td>';
    echo'</tr>';
    echo'</table>';
}
?>
```

CODE FOR `PAGE2.PHP`

```
$lastName = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['lastName']);
$sql =mysql_query ('SELECT name, age, bonus, sex FROM table_1 c join table_2 f on c.lastname = f.lastname where c.lastname  = $lastname ' )
or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
while ($row) {
    // Echo page content
    echo $row['name'].'<br>';
    echo $row['age'];
    echo $row['sex'];
    echo $row['bonus'];
}
?>
```

When i clicked on "View Details" in `page1.php`, I get this error `Unknown column '$lastname' in 'where clause'`

Comment: Do you have ownership over those tables (that is, are you creating the database schema, or is it pre-existing database?

Comment: Nick Bailey. Thanks for your concern. I already have the databse in my local machine. I just need to use page1.php as a masterPage to display the content of the two tables in page2 (another page, which i may call the Detail page) using one of the returned data in page1 as a link

Comment: I would recommend if you're just starting out with MySQL / PHP to very importantly looking into MySQLi or PDO with PHP, as the standard MySQL is insecure and deprecated and the two newer variants above are a much more futureproof and improved way of programming.

Comment: @ Thats good idea. I hope to begin to google that as soon as possible, hoping to succeed. thanks so much. Any available resource site or material from you would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: please i have an additional issue. i dont know if i should open a new question on this. BUT page2.php displays nothing when where are number of places where 'table1.lastname' = 'table2.lastname'. what do i do? I need to display the joined/combined records of the two tables in DESC order no mather the number of instances where tables1.lastname = table2.lastname. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You must put $lastname inside `'` because the type of this field in the database is varchar or text.

In your `z2.php`

```
<?php

$lastName = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['lastName']);

$sql = "SELECT name, age, bonus, sex FROM table_1 c join table_2 f on c.lastname = f.lastname where c.lastname  = '" .  $lastname . "'" ;

$result = mysql_query($sql); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // Echo page content
    echo $row['name'].'<br>';
    echo $row['age'];
    echo $row['sex'];
    echo $row['bonus'];
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian. I have just modified the query as you instructed, but i am not yet there. i modified the SELECT as follows: $sql =mysql_query ("SELECT name, age, bonus, sex FROM table_1 c join table_2 f on c.lastname = f.lastname where c.lastname  =  '".$lastname." ' " )or die(mysql_error()); The error message i get is: Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in C:\ONE\htdocs\exer\z2.php on line 30

Comment: Wow. Where is the error for me to correct. I have checked the variable to ensure coreespondence with the field names in the database

Comment: @ Adrian, thanks so much. It worked. am so happy. You are the best. I seek to do something for you in reward. May i know what i did not do well. I am just trying to learn php from the scratch. i hope to succeed